# Berkshelf command error

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, berkshelf

I have installed the gem berkshelf (2.0.10).

My Berksfile

```
site :opscode 
cookbook 'memcached', '~> 1.3.0'
cookbook 'redisio', '~> 1.4.1'.
```

I execute the command berks.

```
/chef-repo$ berks
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/likewise-open/ZOHOCORP/siva-pt130/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3 (Errno::EACCES)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `fu_mkdir'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `reverse_each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `block in mkdir_p'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `mkdir_p'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in `write_gem_make_out'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `rescue in build_extension'
```

Comment: changing the permission of the file reported in the error gives solution. and I set 777 permission to the directory where permission have to be applied.

Comment: Are you using the system ruby? You probably need sudo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the system ruby, you need to run:

```
sudo berks
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with bundler/rubygems 2.2. See [bundler#2847](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2847). The suggested solution is to downgrade to rubygems 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and was able to resolve it with:

`sudo chown -R myusername:staff /Users/myusername/.berkshelf/cookbooks`

I noticed that a few of my cookbook directories under .berkshelf were owned by root instead of me. This happens when if you run berks with sudo when installing or updating a cookbook.